# mockito when - then return error

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void testGenerateFileName(){

GregorianCalendar mockCalendar = Mockito.mock(GregorianCalendar.class);
Date date = new Date(1000);
Mockito.when(mockCalendar.getTime()).thenReturn(date);  
...
}
```

At the third line I am getting the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  Date cannot be returned by getTimeInMillis() getTimeInMillis() should return long
*** If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Why is this happening? I'm not using `getTimeInMillis()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method `GregorianCalendar.getTime()` is final, so Mockito cannot intercept the method call.

An alternative is to use Apache commons lang to transform the date to a `Calendar`, so when you call `getTime` it returns the value you expect

```
DateUtils.toCalendar(date)
```

If you want to go wild, you can use PowerMock to mock final fields, but I think it's not worth adding the complexity of PowerMock, when you have a simpler alternative.

And another point. You should try to avoid mocking objects that you don't own, this is quite an important point about unit testing and mock objects. Here's one [reference](http://stevef.truemesh.com/archives/000194.html) that has some links about this practice.

And last, as it might apply to your project: it's quite a good practice to introduce a "Clock" object from where you can get the current time, and tests can manipulate this clock to return a "static" current time.

## Edit

Java 8 includes the [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) abstraction, which has concrete implementations ideal for testing which can be obtained by calling `Clock.fixed()`, `Clock.tick()`,  `Clock.tickSeconds()` and  `Clock.tickMinutes()`... Or you can write your own implementation of Clock.